# how to translate an object from its current position to another one ? (successives translations)

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, storyboard

I managed to developp a storyboard to translate an object from its initial position to another position, but when I trigger the storyboard a second time, or call another storyboard, the object always translate from its initial position, not from the new one established after the first translation. How to change it ?

My code :

```
 TranslateTransform animatedTranslateTransform = new TranslateTransform();
 this.RegisterName("slide", animatedTranslateTransform);
 TransformGroup transformGroup = new TransformGroup();
 transformGroup.Children.Add(animatedTranslateTransform);
 _button.RenderTransform = transformGroup;

 //translate Y
 DoubleAnimation slideDown = new DoubleAnimation(20, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));
 Storyboard.SetTargetName(slideDown, "slide");
 Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(slideDown, new PropertyPath(TranslateTransform.YProperty));
 storyBoardSlideDown.Children.Add(slideDown);
```

Comment: Show us some code. What have you done? What have you tried? What isn't working like you expect? What is it doing instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [DoubleAnimation.By](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.doubleanimation.by.aspx) instead of DoubleAnimation.To. From MSDN:

> The animation progresses from the base value of the property being
>   animated or a previous animation's output value to the sum of that
>   value and the value specified by the By property

Write

```
DoubleAnimation slideDown =
    new DoubleAnimation { By = 20, Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0) };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the FillBehavior of your animation (such as DoubleAnimation) to HoldEnd:

```
da.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.HoldEnd;
```

Then set the da.From property to the Top or Left of your Canvas or Element object.

If your object can move both vertically and horizontally, you will need two DoubleAnimation objects attached to your storyboard.

Comment: Default value for the FillBehavior property is already HoldEnd. My object moves (20 px bottom in my sample code) and stay in position after animation, but I would like it to move to another 20 px bottom (so 40 px from initial position) if I trigger the animation again (=> it should move from its new position, not from the initial one).